# How to update checkout/cart/ orders total when promo code is applied dynamically without page reload

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, knockoutjs, coupon

I have changed my `checkout/cart/` page promo code to `ajax` call so that it doesn't get reloaded, while on the success of that ajax call, I have to update the total price summary dynamically without reloading.

How to achieve that.

[image]

Need to update this(price summary) as soon as user apply the promo code, I am using ajax instead of reloading the page as it was happening earlier.

I referred some links,

```
define([
'jquery',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
'OtherDependencies'
], function ($,totalsProvider, quote){
  'use strict';
  //Your code here
  totalsProvider.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());
});
```

How this code supposed to work as i dont have any shippingAddress here.

It just promo code and have to update the subtotal and order total with promo amount applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an action like this:

```
require(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/cache',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
    ],
    function (cartCache, totalsProcessor, quote) {
        cartCache.clear('cartVersion');
        totalsProcessor.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());
    }
);
```

It will update the cart totals from the cart page using default shipping address from the quote. If there was no address it is another issue.

I tested it in the browser console this way:

```
require(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/cache',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
    ],
    function (cartCache, totalsProcessor, quote) {
        var form = jQuery('#discount-coupon-form');
        jQuery.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    cartCache.clear('cartVersion');
                    totalsProcessor.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());
                }
            }
        );
    }
)();
```

and all works fine on Magento 2.3.1 for not logged in customer.

[image: Result]

**PS:** I know that my answer is not a complete, but maybe this information will be useful for you.

---

#### Update:

Here is simplified example:

Add our component which submit coupon code using AJAX and update cart totals:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            submitCoupon: 'Vendor_Module/js/submitCoupon'
        }
    }
};
```

Create js file with action (it is simplified, you need to write own logic):

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/submitCoupon.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/cache',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, cartCache, totalsProcessor, quote) {
    'use strict';

    console.log('Submit coupon loaded');

    var form = $('#discount-coupon-form');

    $('#submit_coupon').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    cartCache.clear('cartVersion');
                    totalsProcessor.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());
                }
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Add simple block with template into layout for the cart page (simplified, you need to write own):

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="submit_coupon" before="-" template="Vendor_Module::coupon.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create template (simplified too, write your own with desired design):

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/coupon.phtml

```
<div id="submit_coupon">
    <?= __('Submit Coupon'); ?>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#submit_coupon": {
            "submitCoupon": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

As a result after clean cache and redeploy static content you will see the `<div>` having a text `Submit Coupon`. When you have press it the coupon code entered in the default input will be sent to a server and after it will be processed the cart totals will be updated.

[image: Example of how it works]

**PPS:** As I said, it is just a very simplified scheme which serves to understand "how it will work". For your purposes you need to write something more complicated and well designed.

Comment: Answer this too https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279918/how-to-add-a-additional-field-in-summary-section-magento-2-3

Comment: @Siarhey '#disount-coupon-form' is the id of which form, you are doing ajax on which form ? total price form ?

Comment: @summu no, it is coupon code form. I use it to send request with a coupon code before update a totals.

Comment: @Siarhey Uchukhlebau Please Answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279918/how-to-add-a-additional-field-in-summary-section-magento-2-3

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau How can I include this require js in my js file, how can I include it, it throws me an error , i used this but it didnt work me https://webkul.com/blog/what-is-requirejs-and-how-to-use-it/

Comment: @summu Hi, I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau thank you

Comment: it is showing Submit Coupon as a text not as a button. Also how to add this functionality in apply button